# Event time zone field not showing in entry form

Tags: civievent, timezone

The event time zone field (new in CiviCRM 5.47) doesn't show up in the "new event" form. Impossible to store a new event to the DB, as the event time zone entry is mandatory.

Joomla 3.10.6 / CiviCRM 5.47

**Where to configure the default time zone for events?

Why does the respective setting not show up in the event form?**

Thanks a lot for your advice.

Comment: Does your site have a customized EventInfo.tpl?

Comment: Yes, it has a customized EventInfo.tpl. Does this have an impact on the backend/form?

Comment: Yes you'll need to merge in changes from civi evey time you upgrade.

Comment: The EventInfo.tpl form in the administration area has NOT been customized, only the frontend template.

Comment: In my test-environment with a completely new installation from scratch, the form is displaying as expected (with the timezone-field).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found out, what was going on. 
**The extension "Advanced Events" is not yet respecting the new timezone setting.**

[image]

[image]

In order to create/administer events, the extension has to be deactivated (not uninstalled).

[image]

[image]

Like this, everything works as expected.

Comment: Good job finding it.

Comment: Thx for your inputs! I informed Matthew about the issue.